# update an entire dictionary in a list of dictionaries based on key value pair

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries and I have to update an entire dictionary based on a specific key-value pair

```
values = [
            {
                "value" : "AAA",
                "rank" : 10,
                "id" : 1
            },
            {
                "value" : "BBB",
                "rank" : 50,
                "id" : 2
            }
]
```

I will receive a new list `value_new = [{"value" : "CCC","rank" : 20,"id" : 1}]`. The idea is to match the id and update the entire dictionary related to that id and sort the entire values list based on rank.

I iterated through values list and matched based on id and when I tried to update it replaced the entire value list

I tried this piece of code

```
for val in range(len(values)):
   if values[val]['id'] == value_new['id']:
     values[val] = value_new
```

I am unable to sort it after appending.

Comment: What you did would have worked except you have bugs in that code. It is not efficient, though. You might consider OrderedDict with id as the key, sorted by rank.

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-a-value-of-the-dictionary)? You might also use the id as a key for the specific dictionaries.

Comment: I tried 
        values[val] and value[new][0] and the issue got resolved. The dictionary was replaced as an entire list which was the cause of the issue

Answer (score 1):

I attempted to replicate what you want to do with this code:

```py
values = [
            {
                "value" : "AAA",
                "rank" : 10,
                "id" : 1
            },
            {
                "value" : "BBB",
                "rank" : 50,
                "id" : 2
            }
]

print(values)

value_new = [{
                "value" : "CCC",
                "rank" :20,
                "id" : 1
            }]

# code for editing here
for val in values:
    if value_new[0]['id'] == val['id']:
        for key in value_new[0]:
            val[key] = value_new[0][key]

print(values)
```

This changed the dictionary as you described:

Before:

```py
[{"value" : "AAA", "rank" : 10, "id" : 1}, {"value" : "BBB", "rank" : 50, "id" : 2}]
```

After:

```py
[{"value" : "CCC", "rank" : 20, "id" : 1}, {"value" : "BBB", "rank" : 50, "id" : 2}]
```